# Django Rest Interface - unable to access authenticated user in my resource

Tags: python, django, authentication, rest, interface

I'm using django-rest-interface to build an API. However, when I make a request through curl, say:

```
    curl -u 'username:password' -X PUT --data "field=value" http://127.0.0.1:8080/resource/
```

and try to access the request.user in the get(), post(), put() or delete() method in the resource, I always get an error saying  that I'm accessing AnonymousUser().

How can I authenticate to these methods?

EDIT:

I was able to fix this problem for me by adding request.user=self.user in the function dispatch() in the file views.py of django-rest-framework, right before handler(request, *args, **kwargs).

However, I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from djangorestframework.authentication import BasicAuthentication

class BasicUserAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
   """ A simple wrapper that also sets request.user when using basic auth """

def authenticate(self, request):
    user = super(BasicUserAuthentication, self).authenticate(request)
    if user:
        request.user = user
    return user
```

A neater way to handle this is by subclassing BasicAuthentication, as above. Although it are things like this that make me question django-rest-framework...